# Left and right sides have a different number of elements

Tags: matlab

When I am trying to execute this code, I get an 'Unable to perform assignment because the left and right sides have a different number of elements.' error. Where is the problem? Thanks for helping.

```
A = 1250; 
Q = 450; 
t = (0:0.5:10);
y(1) = 0;
for i = 1:length(t)
    y(i+1) = y(i) + [(3*(Q/A).*sind(t).^2)-(Q/A)].*0.5;
end
display(y);
```

Comment: The message is very clear. You are trying to assign `y(i) + [(3*(Q/A).*sind(t).^2)-(Q/A)].*0.5` (size 21 x 1)  to `y(i)` (size 1). They have different number of elements

Comment: I'm trying to find new result for every y(i). For instance, y(1)=0, y(2)=-0.18, y(3)=-0.2359.... until y(20). Why program accepted that as a size 1, i'm trying to create array for y(i) values.

Comment: The left side of the equation is a single element. On the right hand side you are performing some operation on the whole vetor of t which will result in an array. Assigning an array to a single element won't work and that is what Matlab is telling you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `for` loop, you assign an expression (the RHS) to an array (the LHS). `y(i)` is a `1x1` array, and the RHS has the same dimensions as `t` (`1x21`). You cannot assign 21 values to an array that can only hold one. To repair, I'd suggest preallocating `y`, with the line

```
y = zeros(numel(t), numel(t))
```

or, what I think you probably intended, only call one element of `t` at a time

```
y(i+1) = y(i) + [(3*(Q/A).*sind(t(i)).^2)-(Q/A)].*0.5;
```

As an aside, it is bad practice to use `i` as a variable as it already has a built-in value in Matlab. For loop indices I usually use `ii`, `jj` or `k`.

Comment: I did it with y=zeros(size(t)) and it works and i'll look for your suggestion using ii, jj or k. Thank you so much.